# Jquery Hide search box when click outside the search box

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to Jquery and have a little problem with the Jquery function. I got the code from somewhere and would like to add a little function like click anywhere except the search box will hide the search box.

here's the code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

// Search
$('ul.tert-nav li.searchit').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('search');
    $('.searchbox').fadeIn();
    $('ul.tert-nav li img.searchicon').hide();
});


$('ul.tert-nav li.searchit img.closesearch').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.searchbox').hide();
    $('ul.tert-nav li').removeClass('search');
});

})
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="tert-nav">
    <li><img alt="" border="0" src="images/icon-cart.png" width="16" height="16" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" border="0" src="images/icon-tickets.png" width="16" height="16" /></li>
    <li class="searchit">
        <img alt="" border="0" class="searchicon" src="images/icon-search.png" width="16" height="16" />
        <div class="searchbox">
            <img alt="" border="0" class="closesearch" src="images/icon-close.png" width="16" height="16" />
            <input placeholder="search..." type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

ul.tert-nav {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.tert-nav li {
    float: right;
    width: 26px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #3c3c3c;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
}

ul.tert-nav li:hover {
    background: #000;
}

ul.tert-nav .search {
    width: 246px;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: default;
}

ul.tert-nav .search:hover {
    background: #3c3c3c;
}

ul.tert-nav .searchbox {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.tert-nav .searchbox .closesearch {
    float: left;
    margin: 6px 4px 0px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tert-nav .searchbox .closesearch:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;   
}

ul.tert-nav .searchbox input[type=text] {
    float: left;
    width: 184px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: none;
    background: url(images/search-bg.png) no-repeat;
    outline: none;
}

ul.tert-nav .searchbox input[type=submit] {
    float: left;
    width: 26px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    background: url(images/search-btn.png) no-repeat;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

here's an example image of the initial state and the clicked/opened state to give a visual idea of what I'm trying to do. Thanks!
[image]

My Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/johanlie/8doLhp5e/7/

Comment: http://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/qcyGF/ just try this way if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind the event to a container,(here i am binding the event to document itself). And then checks whether the event is not propagating from the search. If it is not from the search, do your stuff.

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".searchit");

    if (!container.is(e.target))
    {
        $('.searchbox').hide();
        container.removeClass('search');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/73/)

Comment: almost perfect Anoop, but when I click on the search box, it hide too. :(

Comment: Thank you Anoop. Its Perfect!

Comment: Anoop, How if I want to show search-icon.png again when the search box hide? I already tried $('ul.tert-nav li img.searchicon').show(); but it can't worked when i include it to another page. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gp7frhzr/9/)

**Updated Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Search
    $('ul.tert-nav li.searchit').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('search');
        $('.searchbox').fadeIn("slow",function(){
            $("input:text").focus();
        });
        $('ul.tert-nav li img.searchicon').hide();
    });


    $('ul.tert-nav li.searchit img.closesearch').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.searchbox').hide();
        $('ul.tert-nav li').removeClass('search');
    });

    $("input:text").blur(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.searchbox').hide();
        $('ul.tert-nav li').removeClass('search');
    });

});
```

Comment: Hemal, How if I want to show search-icon.png again when the search box hide? I already tried $('ul.tert-nav li img.searchicon').show(); but it can't worked when i include it to another page. Thank you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gp7frhzr/13/. Updated the code.Search Icon is visible again on hide.

Comment: Welcome Joe. Glad to hear this.